# File URI - Change domain name

Tags: media, uri

Is it possible to change the domain name when creating urls to the image:

file_create_url($file->uri)

I need the images to say they're coming from another domain, but I can't change the base_url, since we need to keep drupal accessible on origin.

Example

Origin: http://domain1.com/files...

When creating image urls, they will be http://domain2.com/files...

Comment: Yes. Never did, but CDN module does it all the time, so you can see what hooks it implements. If you will figure this out, please share!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [file_create_url()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) I think it should be possible to pass in an absolute path, starting with `/files...` and then prefix the return value with your domain, protocol, whatever you need.

To handle that at a single location in code you can also use [hook_file_url_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_url_alter/7).

Is it possible that you're looking for the [CDN](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDwQFjAA&url=https://drupal.org/project/cdn&ei=DVXoUvGLC8PNtAaX7IDICw&usg=AFQjCNEeVVqVf2QeHfTXxOBhI24zXsEe-Q) module?

Comment: You can use the CDN module in pull origin mode to do this, even if it isn't a real CDN.  I do this to get static assets on cookie free domains.

Comment: Yes, I think the CDN module is what we're looking for, really appreciate the quick response on this!